# Get the duplicate entries from table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have the table structure as shown below. The database is MariaDB.

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| id_object |   name   | value_double | value_timestamp |
+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+
|     1     | price    | 1589         |  null           |
|     1     | payment  | 1590         |  null           |
|     1     | date     | null         |  2012-04-17     |
|     2     | price    | 1589         |  null           |
|     2     | payment  | 1590         |  null           |
|     2     | date     | null         |  2012-04-17     |
|     3     | price    | 1589         |  null           |
|     3     | payment  | 1590         |  null           |
|     3     | date     | null         |  2012-09-25     |
|    ...    | ...      | ...          |  ..             |
+-----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

1) I need to get the duplicates by three entries: price & payment & date;
For example: the record with id_object=2 is duplicate because price, payment and date are the same as values of the record with id_object=1. Record with id_object = 3 is not the duplicate because the date is different (2012-09-25 != 2012-04-17)
2) I should remove the duplicates except one copy of them.

I thought to do three select operations and join each select on id_object. I can get the duplicates by one entry (price | payment | date). I faced the problem doing the joins

```
SELECT `id_object`,`name`,{P.`value_double` | P.`value_timestamp`}
FROM record P
INNER JOIN(
SELECT {value_double | value_timestamp}
FROM record
WHERE name = {required_entry}
GROUP BY {value_double | value_timestamp}
HAVING COUNT(id_object) > 1
)temp ON {P.value_double = temp.value_double | P.value_timestamp = temp.value_timestamp}
WHERE name = {required_entry}
```

Can someone help and show the pure (better) solution?

Comment: When using an EAV model, I prefer to separate attributes out into separate tables according to data type, precisely so you don't end up with all these nulls.

Comment: Can you give the expected result?

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though less efficient than certain alternatives, I find an approach along these lines easier to read...

```
SELECT MIN(id_object) id_object
     , price
     , payment
     , date 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id_object
            , MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'price'   THEN value_double END) price
            , MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'payment' THEN value_double END) payment
            , MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'date'    THEN value_timestamp END) date
         FROM eav
        GROUP 
           BY id_object
     ) x
 GROUP  
    BY price
     , payment
     , date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just `group_concat()` the values together and do the test that way:

```
 select t.*
 from t join
      (select min(id_object) id_object
       from (select id_object,
                    group_concat(name, ':', coalesce(value_double, ''), ':', coalesce(value_timestamp, '') order by name) pairs
             from t
             where name in ('price', 'payment', 'date')
             group by id_object
            ) tt
        group by pairs
     ) tt
     on t.id_object = tt.id_object;
```

To actually delete the ones that are not the minimum `id` for each group of related values:

```
delete t
    from t left join
         (select min(id) as id
          from (select id, group_concat(name, ':', coalesce(value_double, ''), ':', coalesce(value_timestamp, '' order by name) as pairs,
                from t
                where name in ('price', 'payment', 'date')
                group by id
               ) tt
          group by pairs
         ) tt
         on t.id = tt.id
    where tt.id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks! Great solution

Comment: @Miracle633 Praise is sweet, but upvotes are sweeter still ;-)